# Why does Geogebra draw the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ as if it were the function $f(x)=1$?

Tags: graphing-functions

Why does Geogebra draw the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$ as if it were the function $f(x)=1$? I noticed that Wolfram Alpha and Google also draw the former as if it were the latter. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: How do you expect the only difference, a hole at $x=0$, to be drawn? At Desmos, you can only see the hole when you put the cursor right on it.

Comment: Most graphing software plots a bunch of points and connects them.

Comment: Well, I expect some kind of circle in order to make explicit that the function is undefined if $x=0$.

Comment: If anyone knows of a way to at least fix it "in post" so that I can show my calc students a function in GeoGebra with an obvious removable discontinuity, I'd love to hear about it!  Trying to add a tiny circle to the graph ruined an otherwise pleasant day for me a while back.